# Controlling the RPG

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

How does one control the RPG (Launcher) in multiplayer? For me it seems to always go a little too high or straight into the floor, whereas my opponents seem to find my face pretty consistently.

Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry there is no trick to this at all. The only advice I can give is to aim down the sights and crouch, this should limit idle sway which could throw your aim. Aside from that it's pure random chance as to where the rocket goes. There is no way to predict where it will go.

The best way to use it would be to crouch and aim down sight. Also stick to medium range shots. The further away the enemy the more chance there is that the rocket will miss.

Comment: Also, I'll add that when you're facing an enemy, do not attempt to shoot the RPG at him. You have a small target and if you miss him even by a litte, the rocket will fly right by him and not do any damage. Try hitting the ground right by him, or a wall or car if he's standing by one.